# Are all Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis

[Showing that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure (and one more thing).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138965/showing-that-the-lebesgue-stieltjes-measure-is-absolutely-continuous-with-respec)

So in this post, it's easy to show that Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is absolutely continuous if the associated function is continuously differentiable. I'm wondering, if this is true for any Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure?(associated with an increasing, right continuous function.)

Thanks in advance.